# assigning custom class to UIWindow while using storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

In non-storyboard projects i can simply select window in interface builder and change it's class from UIWindow to MyUIWindow. How i am supposed to do it in storyboard project? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403137/sublassing-uiwindow-while-using-storyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppDelegate you have: `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;`
So if you do rest in past but not with storyboard you should be fine from there.