# subclassing UIWindow while using storyboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwindow

I have same issue as explained in this question:

[Where can I change the window my app uses from UIWindow to my own subclass "MyWindow" with storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883886/where-can-i-change-the-window-my-app-uses-from-uiwindow-to-my-own-subclass-mywi)

My question is how do i implement a 'window' getter method in my app delegate that returns 'MyWindow' subclass? Or maybe there is other ways to assign my subclass to my app's main window?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`UIWindow` in a Storyboard project can be subclassed as explained in Apple's `UIApplicationDelegate` reference:

> **window** 
>   When a storyboard is being used, the application must present the
>   storyboard by adding it to a window and putting that window on-screen.
>   The application queries this property for the window. The retained
>   reference to the window by this property is necessary to keep the
>   window from being released. If the value of the property is `nil` (the
>   default), the application creates a generic instance of `UIWindow` and
>   assign it to this property for the delegate to reference. You may
>   implement the getter method of this protocol to provide the
>   application with a different window.

In other words in your `AppDelegate` implementation simply add the following getter

**Objective-C**

```
- (MyCustomWindow *)window
{    
    static MyCustomWindow *customWindow = nil;
    if (!customWindow) customWindow = [[MyCustomWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    return customWindow;
}
```

**Swift**

```
var customWindow: MyCustomWindow?    
var window: UIWindow? {
    get {
        customWindow = customWindow ?? MyCustomWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        return customWindow
    }
    set { }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide how I can override getter in Swift?

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked.I was not creating setter for that so that I was getting error.

Answer (score 3):

Its not so hard you're going to first subclass UIWindow

```
class WinCustom : UIWindow{ 
....
}
```

then in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = WinCustom(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    self.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my own apps, I've seen "`window`" property declared in AppDelegate.h when creating a new app from the Xcode templates.

You can modify that property to change from "`UIWindow`" to "`MyWindow`" at that point.

Or, a less elegant solution, you can simply cast `window`'s return to a "`MyWindow`" object type when accessing it.

Comment: Neither of those will cause a `MyWindow` to get created—they’re just mistakenly casting an already-existing `UIWindow` to a `MyWindow`.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon - vfxdomain probably already now knows how to create a MyWindow (since he referred to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883886/where-can-i-change-the-window-my-app-uses-from-uiwindow-to-my-own-subclass-mywi) in his posting up there). My take on his question was he was wondering how to get MyWindow returned by the getter method of the "`window`" property.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann - yep, that's what i am asking... Changing UIWindow to myWindow in App Delegate won't work as Noah Witherspoon pointed.

Comment: The second sentence in this answer pretty much says "Customize to your liking" yet you have no upvotes! Can people not infer things?? Dear sir, I will give you an up++

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplicationDelegate` protocol has `window` property which you can use

```
import UIKit

class CustomWindow : UIWindow {
    //...
}
```

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var customWindow: CustomWindow?

    var window: UIWindow? {
        get {
            customWindow = customWindow ?? CustomWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            return customWindow
        }
        set { }
    }

    //...
}
```

This solution just returns a custom UIWindow

[[Set UIWindow]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61506795/4770877)

Comment: A protocol does not decide whether a property is computed or not. That's just wrong.