# Detecting shake in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, appdelegate, shake

How can I detect a device shake in the AppDelegate (across the entire app) in Swift?

I've found answers that describe how to do so in a view controller, but looking to do so across my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following snippet in your `AppDelegate`:

```
override func motionBegan(motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
        print("Device shaken")
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.0 version:**

```
override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        print("Device shaken")
    }
}
```

### As for later versions this does not seem to work anymore. You need to add the above code in your view controller instead

Comment: This did not work, since the app delegate is not in the responder chain.

Comment: @SaRaVaNaNDM, sure it is just tested it and have tested it before. Did you get any errors? How did you implement it?

Comment: Same as the way you suggested in Swift 3.0 version. Do i need to do anything else ?

Comment: That is enough with the code above. Are you trying on a real device? @SaRaVaNaNDM

Comment: Worked on real device  iPad 2/9.3, swift 3.0.2 for me.

Comment: @SaRaVaNaNDM, this seems to be blocked now. You need to add the code in your view controller instead.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to globally detect shake motion, the UIWindow implements UIResponder that can receive shake motion event. You can add the following snippet to AppDelegate

```
extension UIWindow {
    open override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if motion == .motionShake {
            print("Device shaken")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Just adding it (without the UIWindow extension) didn't work when I put it in the app delegate. Had to add `open` in front of func for iOS 10.3/Xcode8.3.

Comment: Quite strange, motionBegan get called, but motionEnded doesn't.

Comment: After trying many other solutions, this is the only one that works for me. Also, I learned that I can override functions in extensions. Awesome!

Comment: Bad idea to use the extension. Provide your own  subclass, define the method in it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10580083/1633251 . You can then pass the events to super - maybe they are needed there.

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 4 or 5, it's `UIEvent.EventSubtype`, not `UIEventSubtype`.

Also don't forget to add a call to `super.motionEnded(motion, with: event)`. This preserves any motionEnded customizations on your view controllers.

```swift
extension UIWindow {
    open override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.motionEnded(motion, with: event)
        
        if motion == .motionShake {
            print("Device shaken")
        }
    }
}
```